# Array of Multiple items in Swagger

Tags: node.js, mongodb, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

So I'm creating a user endpoint with nodejs to add a user to the database , and for the api documentation I'm using swagger editor and I'm completely new to it.
what I want to do is add a user with login , password , avatar but that user has multiple roles I want to add to the database 
what I have done in the yaml document in the swagger editor is this

```
/users/add:
post:
description: ''
operationId: AddUser
parameters:
- description: The user login
  in: formData
  name: user
  required: true
  type: string
- description: The user password
  in: formData
  name: password
  required: true
  type: string
- description: The user name
  in: formData
  name: username
  required: true
  type: string
- description: The user avatar
  in: formData
  name: avatar
  required: true
  type: file
- in: formData
  name: roles
  description: roles
  required: false
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
    collectionFormat: multi
```

and it's kind of displaying what I want in the swagger editor
[image]

but what i'm getting in the UI is just an input field
[image]

In conclusion what I want to get is an inputted array which contains the user roles and input them in the database.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Swagger UI are you using?  I am on version 2.1.1 and when I put the same definition as you I get the following input box for an array field.

[image: swagger array parameter]

Try upgrading to the newest version of Swagger UI.

Also, if you update the "in" field to be "query" the resulting URL will look like this:

`http://localhost:8080/accounts?roles=admin%2Cguest%2Cuser`

You can then access the array values in the URL parameters rather than in "formData".

Comment: Thank you , it works fine now , it was actually the Swagger UI version I was using , it was 2.0.0.